# Can you identify this font (Human Fund)?

Tags: font-identification

I used a couple of online services but couldn't manage to identify the font in the well known George Costanza *Human Fund* holiday card:

[image]

I'd like to know the font used for the *"To celebrate the holiday season, a charitable...*" part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bookman Old Style](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/bookman-old-style/bookman-old-style/)

---

[image]
[image]

---

Although it may be some other slight variation of Bookman rather than the specific version I've linked to above.